# How to align last list item to bottom with responsive positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation column on the left side of the window and I need to position the last navigation item at the bottom of the column. However, I need that item also move up to its normal position below the second to last list item if the window is resized and the height decreases.

I'm using React and Material-UI's List and ListItem components to create this navigation column. They render as a `<ul>` with `<li>` tags inside.

I've tried using position: fixed, bottom: 0 on the last `<li>` tag which positions it correctly at the bottom, but when the window is resized, it overlaps the other list items.

I've also tried setting the `<ul>` to display: flex, flex-direction: column and then setting the last `<li>` margin-top to some value...but I really don't want to set a value for this because it's supposed to be responsive.

This is as close as I've made it - [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/navigation-bottom-align-rrbn2). What CSS can I use to make the last list item at the bottom and move it up when the screen/window is resized?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there with `flex`. Use `margin-top:auto` on the last `<li>`:

```css
html {height:100%}
body {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  border: solid;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

li:last-of-type {margin-top:auto}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li class="right">THIS ONE FLEX END</li>
</ul>
```